# Getting the difference value from 2 different lists´ hashes in perl

Tags: perl, hash

There are 2 lists of hashes:

```
my  @family1= (
{
   husband  => "barney",
   wife     => "betty",
   son      => "bamm bamm",
},
   husband => "george",
   wife    => "jane",
   son     => "elroy",
},
);

my @family2{
   wife    => "jane",
},
);
```

The structures of keys are different in both lists, and I need to get key 'wife'  that is not in @family1, for instance in this case "betty".

I have thought to do something like:

```
foreach my $f1(@family1)
{
   foreach my $f2 (@family2)
   {
     if (($f1->{wife} ne $f2 -> {wife})
      { 
       print MYFILE Dumper ($f1->{wife});
      }
   }
}
```

When I do something like it dont get what I expect. I get n times f1->{wife} and I would like to get just:

```
@sameWife = ("betty");
```

Does anyone have a better solution? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
my @sameWife = grep {
      my $wife = $_;                         # wife from @family1
      grep { $wife ne $_->{wife} } @family2; # take $wife if she isn't in @family2
    }
    map { $_->{wife} }                       # we want just wife, not whole hash
    @family1;
```

or maybe simpler to read:

```
my @sameWife = map {
      my $wife = $_->{wife};        # wife from @family1
      my $not_in_family2 = grep { $wife ne $_->{wife} } @family2;
      $not_in_family2 ? $wife : (); # take $wife if she isn't in @family2
    }
    @family1;
```

Comment: Thanks. Now I want to add one more condition `my $not_in_family2 = grep { $wife ne $_->{wife} and $son eq "elroy" } @family2;` with the ´eq´ condition works perfectly but ´ne´ shows all elements.

Answer (score 1):

Different approach:

```
my %foo; # temp hash
# only use the wife from each has; parens are to seperate the two maps
$foo{$_}++ for ( map { $_->{wife} } @family1 ), map { $_->{wife} } @family2;
# only use the names that appear once
print grep { $foo{$_} == 1 } keys %foo;
```